# combine list of data frames in list in specific manner

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I got a list which have another list of data frames.
The outside list elements represents years and inside list represent months data.

Now I want to create a final list which will contain data for all months. Each Month columns will be "cbinded" by other years column values.

```
   Alldata <- list()

Alldata[[1]] <- list(data.frame(Jan_2015_A=c(1,2), Jan_2015_B=c(3,4)), data.frame(Feb_2015_C=c(5,6), Feb_2015_D=c(7,8)))
Alldata[[2]] <- list(data.frame(Jan_2016_A=c(1,2), Jan_2016_B=c(3,4)), data.frame(Feb_2016_C=c(5,6), Feb_2016_D=c(7,8)))
```

Expected output list is as following

[image]

I've tried using `for` loops and its little complex, I want any R function to do this task.

I have done this using for loops using following code. But this is really complex and I myself found this little complicate. Hope I will get any simpler and tidy code for this operation.

## I  created list with each months and years data as a list item in form of data frames

```
x2 <- list()

for(l1 in 1: length(Alldata[[1]])){
  temp <- list()
  for(l2 in 1: length(Alldata)){


    temp <- append(temp, list(Alldata[[l2]][[l1]]))

  }

  x2 <- append(x2, list(temp))
}

# then created final List with succesive years data of each month as list items. This is primarily used for Tracking data for years For Example:  how much was count was for Jan_2015 and Jan_2016 for "A"
finalList <- list()
for(l3 in 1: length(x2)){

  temp <- x2[[l3]]
  td2 <-  as.data.frame(matrix("", nrow = nrow(temp[[1]])))
  rownames(td2)[rownames(temp[[1]])!=""] <- rownames(temp[[1]])[rownames(temp[[1]])!=""]
  for(l4 in 1:ncol(temp[[1]])){
    for(l5 in 1: length(temp)){

      # lapply(l4, function(x)  do.call(cbind, 
      td2 <- cbind(td2, temp[[l5]][, l4, drop=F])
    }

  }

  finalList <- append(finalList, list(td2))

}

> finalList
[[1]]
  V1 Jan_2015_A Jan_2016_A Jan_2015_B Jan_2016_B
1             1          1          3          3
2             2          2          4          4

[[2]]
  V1 Feb_2015_C Feb_2016_C Feb_2015_D Feb_2016_D
1             5          5          7          7
2             6          6          8          8
```

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: @C_Z_ Please see updated question with my code using for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following below.  The `lapply` will iterate over the outer list and the `do.call` will `cbind` the inner list of data frames.

```
lapply(Alldata, do.call, what = 'cbind')
[[1]]
  Jan_2015_A Jan_2015_B Feb_2015_C Feb_2015_D
1          1          3          5          7
2          2          4          6          8

[[2]]
  Jan_2016_A Jan_2016_B Feb_2016_C Feb_2016_D
1          1          3          5          7
2          2          4          6          8
```

You can also use `dplyr` to get the same results.

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(Alldata, bind_cols)
```

Here is a third option proposed by J.R.

```
lapply(Alldata, Reduce, f = cbind)
```

**EDIT**

After clarification from OP, the above solution has been modified (see below) to produce the newly specified output.  The solution above has been left there since it is a building block for the solution below.

```
pattern.vec <- c("Jan", "Feb")
### For a given vector of months/patterns, returns a
### list of elements with only that month.
mon_data <- function(mo) {
  return(bind_cols(sapply(Alldata, function(x) { x[grep(pattern = mo, x)]})))
}
### Loop through months/patterns.
finalList <- lapply(pattern.vec, mon_data)
finalList

## [[1]]
##   Jan_2015_A Jan_2015_B Jan_2016_A Jan_2016_B
## 1          1          3          1          3
## 2          2          4          2          4
## 
## [[2]]
##   Feb_2015_C Feb_2015_D Feb_2016_C Feb_2016_D
## 1          5          7          5          7
## 2          6          8          6          8

## Ordering the columns as specified in the original question.
## sorting is by the last character in the column name (A or B)
## and then the year.
lapply(finalList, function(x) x[ order(gsub('[^_]+_([^_]+)_(.*)', '\\2_\\1', colnames(x))) ])
## [[1]]
##   Jan_2015_A Jan_2016_A Jan_2015_B Jan_2016_B
## 1          1          1          3          3
## 2          2          2          4          4
## 
## [[2]]
##   Feb_2015_C Feb_2016_C Feb_2015_D Feb_2016_D
## 1          5          5          7          7
## 2          6          6          8          8
```

Comment: nice,  or `lapply(Alldata, Reduce, f = cbind)` to emphasize a reduction.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for the alternative.  I can add it to my answer if you are not planning on providing it as an answer, your call.

Comment: Go ahead and add it :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the output u provided is merged inner list data frame. Sorry for late editing but I have updated question with added expected final output list.

Comment: I updated my question with desired output created using for loops. Can anyone please simplify this using compact code?

Comment: @indra_patil Please let me know if the edit addresses your desired result.

Comment: @steveb This is perfect output Steve. But the example I posted is a hypothetical example. and above code completes the requirement of above example(Months and Years).
Actual requirement is that: I need subsequent column of each data frame of different list. Like: First list will contain data frame created with cbind([[1]][[1]][[1]][, 1], [[2]][[2]][[1]][, 1]) and so on for the second column, third column etc.SO this will be generic code, cause we may not have same column names as you used to order the data frame.